# Can I use Custom Select Box to process the value of element with Php?

Tags: javascript, php

Maybe this is a stupid question but I am trying to think right!

I made a Custom Select Box..

Html:

```
<div class="select_box">                        
<div class="select_box_header">Show User Group <span><!--SelectArrow--> </span></div>
<!--select_user-->

<div class="option_box">
    <h3>Group 1</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" name="user_group" id="UserA" value="UserA">
    <label for="UserA">User A</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="user_group" id="UserB" value="UserB">
    <label for="UserB">User B </label>

    <h3>Group 2</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" name="user_group" id="UserC" value="UserC">
    <label for="UserC">User C</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="user_group" id="UserD" value="UserD">
    <label for="UserD">User D </label>                              
 </div><!--option_box-->

 </div><!--select_box-->
```

It is working pretty good with some css and js to make changes on client-side.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/jakptq60/4/

My question is: How can I use that Custom select box to process data via Php? Like: As an option selected send it to database etc.. Is that possible?

I have tried something like that but, I don't get respond:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['user_group'])) {
    $user_group = $_POST['user_group'];
    echo $user_group;
    }
?>
```

Comment: You have normal form controls, so … the same way as with a select.

Comment: @Quentin I have tried with a small script.. no action! Please see my question, edited. Is it wrong?

Comment: @PHPglue Do you mean submitting the form without reloading page(with submit button) using AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it out!

html:

```
<div class="option_box">
    <h3>Group 1</h3>
    <form action="" method="post" id="myForm">
    <input type="checkbox" name="user_group" id="autosave" value="UserA">
<label for="UserA">User A</label>
    </form>             
</div><!--option_box-->
```

php:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['user_group']))
    {
    echo "checked";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "not checked";
    }   
?>
```

and subit the checkbox without submit button with jQuery:

```
$("#autosave").click(function(){
  $("#myForm").submit()
});
```

That way I can use my Custom Select Box both client-side and server-side:)

Comment: You don't want to put a form element inside your select box, but your select box inside a form element since you can only send one form per page request at a time and I assume you want to have the ability to have more form elements inside your form, when you submit it.

Comment: @DecentDabbler
Thanx for you for the comment but I don't use an actual select box; it is just a div which has select box behaviors. I just want to use that custom select box with input checkboxes in it(to be able to create a select dropdown option effect..) That works on client-side manipulations just fine but, I want it to work with server-side interactions..

Comment: I understand this, but I assume you want the ability to use your custom select box in a form with other (custom or regular) form elements as well, no? You see: you are not allowed to nest form elements. So `general form > your custom select > custom select form` will not work. If you don't mind this, then you can ignore my comments. But I will say that putting a form element inside a custom form element is rather unorthodox. It makes more sense to wrap a form element around your custom element, so you are more flexible with your custom element.

Comment: As far as I know I am not trying to combine form elements in a form:) What I am trying to do is: Make a div element, looks like select box and acts like select box, and use input(checkbox) elements to give to my Custom Select Box 'option' effect.. but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing it from hidden checkboxes to a single `<input id="user_group" type="hidden" name="user_group"/>` then updating the jquery to update the hidden #user_group and then getting rid of the name="user_group" from all other elements as that confuses the issue where most browsers take the last value and pass that to the server.

HTML

```
<div class="select_box">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_group" id="user_group"/>                            
    <div class="select_box_header">Show User Group <span> </span></div><!--select_user-->
    <div class="option_box">
        <h3>Group 1</h3>
        <div class="select_me" data-val="UserA">User A</div>
        <div class="select_me" data-val="UserB">User B </div>
        <h3>Group 2</h3>
        <div class="select_me" data-val="UserC">User C</div>
        <div class="select_me" data-val="UserD">User D </div>
    </div><!--option_box-->
 </div><!--select_box-->
```

JS

```
$('.select_box_header span').addClass('nonActiveSpan');
$('.select_box_header').click(function(){
    $('.select_box').toggleClass('activeSelect'); //Open Select Box 
    $('.select_box_header span').toggleClass('nonActiveSpan activeSpan'); // Toggle Dropdown Arrow      
});

/* Check if Custom Checkbox is being checked..*/
$('.select_me').on('click', function(){
    $('#user_group').val($(this).attr('data-val'));
    $('.select_box_header').html($('#user_group').val());
    $('.select_box').toggleClass('activeSelect'); //Open Select Box 
    $('.select_box_header span').toggleClass('nonActiveSpan activeSpan'); // Toggle Dropdown Arrow      
});
```

You'll want to play with it to make it look nice and not get rid of the arrow when you select a value, and to be able to select the "no value" option again. but this is should answer how to do this.

in your PHP script you just use `$_REQUEST['user_group']` to access your variable.